# How can I change "page" (as in foobar.com/page/5) to another word?

Tags: pages

I would like the URLs for "pages" on my blog (which is to say the collections of titles and excerpts fpr 10 entries) to be called something else, such as "groups", so that the URL for the page for the 10 most recent entries would be `www.[foobar].com/group/1`, and so on. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Make the title of your blog page `Groups` and the permalink slug for it `groups`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function re_write_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->pagination_base    = 'group';
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 're_write_rules');
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. It works. But doesn't `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` on `init` slow things down quite a bit? I was wondering whether there might be a way round that.